# to get dropdown value in JavaScript on a web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications

How to get value of dropdown selection
With JavaScript.I am try to get values of
Dropdown selection but I don't success this project.**Please help me** **I am continue a web application project with JavaScript**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Also repeating a non-question several times is not helping us helping you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks to your answer&help friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment you to use jQuery. Once you have jQuery all you need is `$("#idOfSelection").val()` to get your value. Without jQuery you would need `document.getElementById("idOfSelection").value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of your drop down using this code. This is applicable in javascript and jquery enabled environment.

```
$("select[title='Status'] option:selected").text()
```